JsonSerializerOptions global setting in .NET 8
Before .NET 8 setting global settings in an Azure Function used to work just fine. Now this same code doesn't work in .NET 8 and Azure Functions v4:
        // Setting global System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions
        services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
            options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault;  // Property is ignored if its value is null. This is applied only to reference-type properties and fields.
        });

Is this no longer supported? I cannot find any documentation how to do it in .NET 8.

System.Text.Json doesn't have global options, see How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?.  Instead, each service has its own default options.  So, did something change with how you are invoking the serializer between .NET 7 and .NET 8?  For instance, did you switch to using a minimal API?

Only thing that switched was me using .NET 6 and 7 previously and still using Azure Functions. Microsoft has this in their docs so global must work somehow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#customizing-json-serialization

I'm not sure then.  Can you add a full [mcve] showing your full new HostBuilder() statement and how you invoked the serializer?  I notice the docs state that The following example shows this using ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication, but it will also work for ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults but it's not clear which you are using.  Is there any chance you are using both?

I am using ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication with a new Function app that is created with the latest VS 2022 and latest Azure Function project template.

@dbc The serializer is invoked like this: var messageData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(message.Body);
If I provide an options configuration inside the Function it works just fine: var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
var messageData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(message.Body, options);

If you are invoking the serializer directly you must pass in the options yourself, because System.Text.Json does not have mutable global default options.  See How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer and Api proposal: Change JsonSerializerOptions default settings #31094 which was closed as "not planned" by MSFT.

Also, might you please [edit] your question to share your code + [mcve] in the question itself rather than in comments?  Thanks!

@dbc I've made it work by look at the old posts that mentions that it needs to be injected. I've now posted an answer.

In .NET 8 I need to inject it to my Azure Functions constructor to work. Here is an example of injecting JSON serialization options into my primary constructor:
public class Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IOptions<JsonOptions> jsonOptions)
{
   private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger = logger;
   private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _jsonOptions = jsonOptions.Value.SerializerOptions;
   ...
}

and then using it in the Deserialize method as paramater:
var messageData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyDTO>(message.Body, _jsonOptions);

This applies my settings for disregarding the casing of field names in JSON.
